# ReactiveCocoa combine SignalProducers into one

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I'm using ReactiveCocoa and I have several SignalProducers

```
let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let signalProducer1 = center.rac_notification(name: notificationName1, object: nil)
let signalProducer2 = center.rac_notification(name: notificationName2, object: nil)
let signalProducer3 = center.rac_notification(name: notificationName3, object: nil)
```

I want to combine them into a single signal producer that produces a signal whenever one of them produces a signal.

At first the `combineLatest` function looked like a good solution

```
let combinedProducer = combineLatest(signalProducer1, signalProducer2, signalProducer3)
```

However, according to [this article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/04/03/combinelatest-and-zip-in-reactivecocoa/), the resulting producer only produces its first signal when all the three have produced a signal.

[This interactive diagram](http://neilpa.me/rac-marbles/#merge) shows exactly what I want, so I want to use the `flatten` function with the `.Merge` FlatteningStrategy. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax to achieve this.

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/BasicOperators.md#merging

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve that as follows:

```
let merged = SignalProducer(values: [ signalProducer1, signalProducer2, signalProducer3 ])
    |> flatten(.Merge)
```

Comment: How would you do this in ReactiveCocoa 4?

Answer (score 15):

**Update: RAC 4.2.1 and upwards**

Due to [changes in how `flatten` works](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/2975) we need to help the compiler an be more explicit about the types:

```
let s1: SignalProducer<Int, NSError> = ...
let s2: SignalProducer<Int, NSError> = ...
let s3: SignalProducer<Int, NSError> = ...


let _: SignalProducer<Int, NSError> =
    SignalProducer<SignalProducer<Int, NSError>, NSError>(values: [s1, s2, s3])
        .flatten(.Merge)
```

That becomes a bit cumbersome, so you might want to split it:

```
let producers: SignalProducer<SignalProducer<Int, NSError>, NSError> =
    SignalProducer(values: [s1, s2, s3])

let merged: SignalProducer<Int, NSError> = x.flatten(.Merge)
```

Thanks @Harry for the comment pointing the new version issue out.

---

**RAC 4.2 and below**

In RAC 4 this would be

```
let merged = SignalProducer(values: [signalProducer1, signalProducer2, signalProducer3])
  .flatten(.Merge)
```

At the moment Xcode 7.1.1 doesn't suggest `.flatten` in the autocompletion window, which might result in you (*or just me*) thinking it is not there, but if you type it all it will work.

Comment: This no longer works with ReactiveCocoa 4.2.1 and above it seems

Comment: Sorry to go back on my previous comment, but this issue was actually fixed in 4.2.2. I believe the issue itself was introduced in 4.2.0.

Comment: Hi @Harry, I am still seeing the issue, and I'm actually using `master`, so what's going to be version 5.0. Any ideas?