# Using combineLatest with UITextFields in RAC 3+

Tags: swift, uitextfield, reactive-cocoa-3

I would like to simply "combine" the signals emitted by a number of textfields and fire a block of code. It seems there are a few ways this "should" work using methods like `combineLatest()` or the `values:` SignalProducer initializer.  But I am not able to get anything to compile or function as expected.

RAC documentations uses the following example

```
combineLatest(numbersSignal, lettersSignal)
  |> observe(next: println, completed: { println("Completed") })
```

But I am not able to compile this kind of usage

I am able to do the following with redundant blocks...

```
locationTextfield.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()
  |> start(next: { txt in
    println(txt)
  })

aircraftTextfield.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()
  |>  start(next: { txt in
    println(txt)
  })
```

I also am not understanding why I need to use `toSignalProducer()` and start rather than just observing the `rac_textsignal` itself.  This "compiles" but nothing seems to be sent on the signal unless a producer is created and started.

This question/answer [ReactiveCocoa combine SignalProducers into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210564/reactivecocoa-combine-signalproducers-into-one) also works, but still seems like a work around, and doesn't explain why signal producers need to be created rather than observing the original `rac_textSignal()`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing `rac_textSignal` without transformations is possible, we just need to clarify that [`rac_textSignal` is `RACSignal`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Objective-C/UITextField%2BRACSignalSupport.h). RACSignal is the ReactiveCocoa 2.0 signal and is related to the Objective-C version. So you need to apply RAC2 operators to such signals, `combineLatestWith:` could help you to solve such task.

Transformations are necessary to apply Swift operators due to diff in the basic concept in RAC3. In RAC2 such core entity was `RACSignal`, against `Signal` and `SignalProducer` in the RAC3.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize structures for RAC2 were still in RAC3.  That makes sense.  Is there an appropriate way to accomplish the same functionality using RAC3's `Signal` and `SignalProducer`?  Or do extensions need to be created to get a `Signal` from a textfield, and not a `RACSignal`?

Comment: @MichaelBopp, early RAC 3.0 releases would have no UIKit extensions (more about this here https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/2074). You could try to search RAC Extensions frameworks, built on the top of ReactiveCocoa, one of them - https://github.com/neilpa/Rex